# How could I reduce repetition with properties/methods?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm serializing instances of a lot of classes (in C# 3.0), and I've found myself writing this:

```
[DataContract]
public class ModelClass
{
    public static Guid GetID(ModelClass instance) { ... }

    public static T FromID<T>(Guid value) where T : ModelClass { }

    [DataMember] public Guid m_id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ConcreteModel: ModelClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string      m_name;

    // Stuff we don't serialize
    public Sector      m_sector;
    public Theater     m_theater;
    public Weather     m_weather;
    public TerrainType m_terrainType;


    // Link serialized ids to real objects through GetID & FromID
    [DataMember] private Guid m_sectorID
    {
        get { return GetID(m_sector); }
        set { m_sector = FromID<Sector>(value); }
    }

    [DataMember] private Guid m_theaterID
    {
        get { return GetID(m_theater); }
        set { m_theater = FromID<Theater>(value); }
    }

    [DataMember] private Guid m_weatherID
    {
        get { return GetID(m_weather); }
        set { m_weather = FromID<Weather>(value); }
    }

    [DataMember] private Guid m_terrainTypeID
    {
        get { return GetID(m_terrainType); }
        set { m_terrainType = FromID<TerrainType>(value); }
    }
}
```

`ConcreteModel` is just one of many (~100) classes that will have some objects that are going to be saved using IDs, but not the whole objects, so we'll have to write that kind of properties a lot of times.

Is there any way of avoiding this? In C++ I'd be using macros, but not in C#...

My main concern here is not writing those properties all over again like 500 times or more. Any idea on how could I avoid that?

Comment: You're pretty much stuck here, unless you generate the code with a `.tt` or use Nemerle or F# (which could actually make sense: they certainly do have macros). This is mostly because you're declaring methods for each property. Roslyn may help eventually. Additionally, since this is CodeReview, I have to comment on the horror of your hungarian notation. I'm fine with your alignment though, assuming you're using elastic tabstops and not spaces.

Comment: @Magus AFAIK, F# doesn't have macros.

Comment: Ah, I overestimated the team's cleverness, then.

Answer (score 2):

As @Magus [commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/how-could-i-reduce-repetition-with-properties-methods#comment85684_48801), this is as good as it gets.

...almost.

```
[DataContract]
public class ConcreteModel: ModelClass
```

```
[DataMember] public Guid m_id { get; set; }
```

```
[DataMember]
public string      m_name;
```

You're not consistent with how you're placing your `DataMemberAttribute` attributes; sometimes they're sitting on top of the decorated member, other times they're stuck in front, on the same line. I'd stick to consistently having them on top.

---

> ```
> // Stuff we don't serialize
> public Sector      m_sector;
> public Theater     m_theater;
> public Weather     m_weather;
> public TerrainType m_terrainType;
> ```

Why are these fields `public` in the first place? You are breaking encapsulation!

> ```
> [DataMember] private Guid m_sectorID
> {
>     get { return GetID(m_sector); }
>     set { m_sector = FromID<Sector>(value); }
> }
> ```

I'm not familiar with serialization using `[DataMemberAttribute]`, but it's rather odd that you expose public fields and declare private serializable properties. Since the fields are exposed anyway, why not just do this?

```
private Sector m_sector;

[DataMember]
public Guid m_sectorID
{
    get { return GetID(m_sector); }
    set { m_sector = FromID<Sector>(value); }
}
```

---

The naming is, as @Magus commented already, breaking all C# naming conventions. Drop the `m_` prefix, and use *PascalCase* for public members:

```
private Sector _sector; // or just "sector"

[DataMember]
public Guid SectorId
{
    get { return GetId(_sector); }
    set { _sector = FromId<Sector>(value); }
}
```

---

If `ModelClass` isn't intended to be instantiated and only serve as a base class, you should make it `abstract` - also "Class" at the end of a class name is rather useless. How about this?

```
public abstract class ModelBase
```

The `public static` members could made non-static, and be `protected` so as to only be exposed to the derived types.

Comment: I think I'd also rename `ModelClass`, but to something slightly different: `YourProgramModel`, `DataModel` or something similar. `Base` can sometimes be a nice suffix to avoid confusion, but it only conveys how it was implemented rather than what it's for, and `Model` is a very generic word which can mean different things in different contexts.